# value of metadata is null wrong use of if statement

Tags: loop, post-meta

I'm using the WP-Ratings plugin which uses the Wordpress built in custom fields to save values of ratings. The name of the custom field is `ratings_score`. I want to ask if each post has a specific rating. What I'm doing is inside the loop doing following:

```
<?php $rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings_score', false); ?> 

<?php if ( $rating == 2 ) ) { ?>
    <script>
        console.log("test");
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

But it does not work. Am I doing it wrong? I also tried to ask `if ( $rating == '2' )` but thats the same issue. There are definately posts which have `2` as value of `ratings_score`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings_score', false); 
var_dump($rating);
```

You will notice that you get an `array`, even if your `ratings_score` is `2`. To wit:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

That will never equal `2` so your condition will never work.

The third parameter of [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) if set to `true` will collapse that array to a scalar, and that will work.

```
$rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings_score', true); 
var_dump($rating);
```

Note that if your post has multiple `ratings_scores` you will only get one of them and it may not be the one you want.

To make this work with multiple `ratings_score` entries use:

```
$rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings_score', false); 

if (in_array(2,$rating)) {
  echo 'found it';
}
```